# Signing and Verifying with OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, rsa, sign, verify

I'm trying to go through the basic exercise of signing and verifying a signature using OpenSSL. Signing works fine

```
$ openssl pkeyutl -hexdump -sign -inkey id_rsa -in test.txt > test.sig
Enter pass phrase for id_rsa:
$ cat test.sig
0000 - 20 ab 34 00 ff 87 50 1e-de fb c9 3d 10 2f 7b fd    .4...P....=./{.
0010 - 99 a1 61 e0 3d 5f 93 82-63 e9 0a 6f 1a 22 4f 04   ..a.=_..c..o."O.
etc...
```

However, when I try to verify that signature, I get an error.

```
$ openssl pkeyutl -verify -pubin -inkey id_rsa.pub.pem -signature test.sig test.txt
unable to load Public Key
```

The public key that I'm trying to use is a converted SSH public key in PEM format:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

generated with the command

```
ssh-keygen -f key.pub -e -m pem
```

Based on discussions and documentation that I've read about this problem, that *should* work. But it doesn't.

Any hints?

---

**EDIT**: I've just tried the same process with a pair of keys generated with OpenSSL rather than converted SSH keys. That merely fails silently rather than producing an error (`openssl` gives me `pkeyutl` usage information rather than verifying the signature).

**EDIT 2**: Using a binary signature (omitting `-hexdump`) has the same effect on keys generated with OpenSSL. On converted RSA keys, I get

```
unable to load Public Key
Error initializing context
[snip usage output]
```

Comment: What implementation/version of OpenSSL are you using?

Comment: @notfed - Sorry, should have mentioned. openssl 1.0.1c-3, straight out of the [Debian Wheezy repos](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/openssl).

Comment: It seems that you are outputting hexdump of the signature to a file and use that for verification. I doubt if openssl expects it read hexdump rather then the binary signature. Could you try removing the "-hexdump" option when generating the signature.

Comment: @RaymondTau - Tried and added notes. Didn't solve the problem, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

You gave non-existing option `-signature`. Correct is `-sigfile`. The following works:

```
$ openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey key.pem -in data.txt > test.sig
$ openssl pkeyutl -verify -pubin -inkey pubkey.pem -sigfile test.sig -in data.txt
Signature Verified Successfully
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-hexdump` option is I guess being used because you dont want to get a binary file out?  You can use `base64` to encode the binary sig as ascii:

```
openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey id_rsa -in test.txt | base64 > test.sig
```

However, when you verify this, you're going to have to convert it back into binary, in some temporary file:

```
cat test.sig | base64 -d > ~test.sig.bin
```

Your public keyfile is in 'rsa public key format', you can see in the header line 'BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY'.  You can convert this into non-rsa public key format, which will have header 'BEGIN PUBLIC KEY':

```
openssl rsa -in id_rsa.pub.pem -RSAPublicKey > id.pub.pem
```

Finally, using the 'PUBLIC KEY' pem, and the binary sigfile, you can verify:

```
openssl pkeyutl -verify -pubin -inkey id.pub.pem -sigfile ~test.sig.bin -in test.txt
```

Output:

```
Signature Verified Successfully
```